# Remove consecutive duplicate values per row in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I am working on a dataset in R where I want to remove consecutive duplicate values PER ROW. 
For example row (19,15,19,19) should become row (19,15,19).

I tried to use duplicated(df) but this removes ALL duplicates resulting in (19,15) instead of only the consecutive duplicates.

Reproducable example:

```
a <- c(19,18,19,9,9,19,19)
b <- c(15,0,19,9,19,19,13)
c <- c(19,0,13,19,19,19,0)
d <- c(19,0,0,19,19,0,0)

trajectories <- cbind(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: How large is your dataset (nrow * ncol)? Should the duplicate values be, really, removed or replaced at their position?

Answer (score 6):

We can loop through the row and get the unique elements based on run-length-encoding to create a `list` of `vector`s

```
lst <- apply(trajectories, 1, FUN = function(x) rle(x)$values)
lst
#[[1]]
# a  b  d 
#19 15 19 

#[[2]]
# a  d 
#18  0 

#[[3]]
# b  c  d 
#19 13  0 

#[[4]]
# b  d 
# 9 19 

#[[5]]
# a  d 
# 9 19 

#[[6]]
# c  d 
#19  0 

#[[7]]
# a  b  d 
#19 13  0
```

We can append `NA` as the end to make the number of elements the same

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
```

#### Update

As @Sotos mentioned, if we need the column names as intact as in the original, then

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(x) {
            x[setdiff(colnames(trajectories), names(x))] <- NA
            x[colnames(trajectories)]}))
```

---

Or another option is to get the `diff`erence between adjacent elements in each row, create a logical vector based on the difference being not zero to subset the elements

```
apply(trajectories, 1, FUN = function(x) x[c(TRUE, diff(x)!=0)])
```

---

Or another option which works on the example

```
 i1 <- which(cbind(1, trajectories[,-1] -
         trajectories[,-ncol(trajectories)])!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)
 lapply(split(1:nrow(i1), i1[,1]), function(i) trajectories[i1[i,, drop = FALSE]])
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! Just one more question: this list has to be converted to a dataframe but I'm not able to do this because every row needs to have the same number of values. Rows with less than 4 values can be filled up with 0's.

Comment: @CharlotteDeVlieghere  You can either `paste` the elements together to create a column or other option is a `list` column in `data.frame`

Comment: The `rbind`ing seems wrong. For example element 4 is `b = 9`, `d = 19`, but when `rbind` is under `a` and `b` columns. I like your last option (anything that doesn't have the margin 1 and `apply`)

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c(19,18,19,9,9,19,19)
b <- c(15,0,19,9,19,19,13)
c <- c(19,0,13,19,19,19,0)
d <- c(19,0,0,19,19,0,0)

trajectories <- cbind(a,b,c,d)
trajectories

t(apply(trajectories, 1, function(x) { x[c(F, diff(x) == 0)] <- 0; x } ))
```

You can set the consecutive duplicate to something else than '0' by changing the `<- 0` part, for example to set them to `NA` instead...

```
t(apply(trajectories, 1, function(x) { x[c(F, diff(x) == 0)] <- NA; x } ))
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so to change duplicates to NA, regardless if they are consecutive or not?

Comment: `t(apply(trajectories, 1, function(x) { x[duplicated(x)] <- NA; x }))`